# Como puedo combinar un DataFrame_Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Buen dia,

Tengo un pregunta no se si alguien me puede dar una idea como lo puedo hacer.
Dispongo del siguiente DataFrame.

```
  OBJECTID    Coord_X        Coord_Y

0     184839;  773866.1055;   9963245.606

1     186563;  773600.2571;     9963150.1

2     186254;  773465.1514;   9963101.804

3     188267;  773464.5314;   9963319.571

4     189278  773843.1493   9963128.459
```

Ahora lo que necesito es combinarlos entre si de tal forma que no se repitan.

Ejemplo:

Combinación de item 0 con 1

```
[(184839,{'Coord_X':773866.1055,'Coord_Y':9963245.606}), (186563,{'Coord_X':773600.2571,'Coord_Y':9963150.1})]
```

Combinación de item 0 con 2

```
[(184839,{'Coord_X':773866.1055,'Coord_Y':9963245.606}), (186254,{'Coord_X':773465.1514,'Coord_Y':9963101.804})]
```

.
.
.
.

Combinación en grupo de 2 de todos los items.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comienzo por cargar los datos que das como ejemplo. En tu caso supongo que los leerás de una excel, o de un CSV o similar, pero aquí voy a optar por leerlos directamente desde una cadena para que cualquiera pueda replicar mi respuesta sin necesidad de tener el archivo correspondiente:

```
data = """
       ;OBJECTID;Coord_X;Coord_Y

0;     184839;  773866.1055;   9963245.606
1;     186563;  773600.2571;     9963150.1
2;     186254;  773465.1514;   9963101.804
3;     188267;  773464.5314;   9963319.571
4;    189278;  773843.1493;   9963128.459
"""
import io
f = io.StringIO(data)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(f, sep=";", index_col=0)
```

Esto nos deja en `df` el siguiente datframe que asumo que es como el que tú tienes:

```
         OBJECTID      Coord_X      Coord_Y

0          184839  773866.1055  9963245.606
1          186563  773600.2571  9963150.100
2          186254  773465.1514  9963101.804
3          188267  773464.5314  9963319.571
4          189278  773843.1493  9963128.459
```

### Solución

Respondiendo ya a tu pregunta, usando `df.to_dict("index")`, pandas permite volcar un dataframe como un diccionario cuyas claves sean los índices de cada fila, y cuyos valores sean otro diccioario con el resto de datos de esa fila (en este diccionario cada clave sería una columna).

Esto está cerca de lo que buscas. Basta cambiar el índice para que sea "OBJECTID":

```
>>> df.set_index("OBJECTID").to_dict("index")
{184839: {'Coord_X': 773866.1055, 'Coord_Y': 9963245.606},
 186254: {'Coord_X': 773465.1514, 'Coord_Y': 9963101.804},
 186563: {'Coord_X': 773600.2571, 'Coord_Y': 9963150.1},
 188267: {'Coord_X': 773464.5314, 'Coord_Y': 9963319.571},
 189278: {'Coord_X': 773843.1493, 'Coord_Y': 9963128.458999999}}
```

El diccionario resultante tiene un método `.items()` que lo muestra como una lista de tuplas, cuyo primer elemento sea la clave y el segundo elemento el valor (el sub-diccionario en este caso).

Es decir:

```
>>>  list(df.set_index("OBJECTID").to_dict("index").items())
[(184839, {'Coord_X': 773866.1055, 'Coord_Y': 9963245.606}),
 (186563, {'Coord_X': 773600.2571, 'Coord_Y': 9963150.1}),
 (186254, {'Coord_X': 773465.1514, 'Coord_Y': 9963101.804}),
 (188267, {'Coord_X': 773464.5314, 'Coord_Y': 9963319.571}),
 (189278, {'Coord_X': 773843.1493, 'Coord_Y': 9963128.458999999})]
```

Una vez lo tenemos de esta forma, tu pregunta equivale a encontrar todas las combinaciones de los elementos de la lista anterior, tomados de 2 en 2.

La biblioteca `itertools` tiene la función `combinations()` que sirve precisamente para esto. Basta pasarle la lista anterior y pedirle combinaciones de 2 en 2:

```
import itertools

for combinacion in itertools.combinations(list(df.set_index("OBJECTID").to_dict('index').items()),2):
  print(list(combinacion))
```

Y sale:

```
[(184839, {'Coord_X': 773866.1055, 'Coord_Y': 9963245.606}), (186563, {'Coord_X': 773600.2571, 'Coord_Y': 9963150.1})]
[(184839, {'Coord_X': 773866.1055, 'Coord_Y': 9963245.606}), (186254, {'Coord_X': 773465.1514, 'Coord_Y': 9963101.804})]
[(184839, {'Coord_X': 773866.1055, 'Coord_Y': 9963245.606}), (188267, {'Coord_X': 773464.5314, 'Coord_Y': 9963319.571})]
[(184839, {'Coord_X': 773866.1055, 'Coord_Y': 9963245.606}), (189278, {'Coord_X': 773843.1493, 'Coord_Y': 9963128.458999999})]
[(186563, {'Coord_X': 773600.2571, 'Coord_Y': 9963150.1}), (186254, {'Coord_X': 773465.1514, 'Coord_Y': 9963101.804})]
[(186563, {'Coord_X': 773600.2571, 'Coord_Y': 9963150.1}), (188267, {'Coord_X': 773464.5314, 'Coord_Y': 9963319.571})]
[(186563, {'Coord_X': 773600.2571, 'Coord_Y': 9963150.1}), (189278, {'Coord_X': 773843.1493, 'Coord_Y': 9963128.458999999})]
[(186254, {'Coord_X': 773465.1514, 'Coord_Y': 9963101.804}), (188267, {'Coord_X': 773464.5314, 'Coord_Y': 9963319.571})]
[(186254, {'Coord_X': 773465.1514, 'Coord_Y': 9963101.804}), (189278, {'Coord_X': 773843.1493, 'Coord_Y': 9963128.458999999})]
[(188267, {'Coord_X': 773464.5314, 'Coord_Y': 9963319.571}), (189278, {'Coord_X': 773843.1493, 'Coord_Y': 9963128.458999999})]
```

que espero sea lo que buscabas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, lo voy a replicar. Saludos cordiales